# how to write if else under return react native

Tags: react-native

hope you are doing well.

I am stuck in little problem is i want to pass a  tag only if my condition goes true.

for ex:

```
render(
   return(
     <View>
         {
          if(data==='test')
            {
              <Text>Hello this is Test Execution </Text>
            }
         }
     </View>
   )
)
```

i want to do exactly like above example.

i get some errors i can't understand what to do so please help me.

Thank you

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A short and safe way would be to use a **ternary operator** and render `null` if false:

```
{ data === 'test' ? <Text>Hello this is Test Execution </Text> : null }
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to write a function which optionally renders your text.

```
  renderText(data) {
      if (data === 'test') {
         return  <Text>Hello this is Test Execution </Text>; 
      }
  }
  render() {
      return(
          <View>
              {this.renderText(data)}
          </View>
      );
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try like

```
{(data === 'test')  && <Text>Hello this is Test Execution</Text>}
```

Hope this will help.

Answer (score 1):

You could try this:

```
render(
   return(
     <View>
         { (data==='test') && <Text>Hello this is Test Execution </Text>}
     </View>
   )
)
```

But I'd suggest the following syntax:

```
render(
  if (data === 'test') {
     return (
        <View>
          <Text>Hello this is Test Execution </Text>
        <View>
     )
  }

  return null;
)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this

```
return(){
    <View>
    {data === 'test' && <Text>Hello this is Test Execution </Text>}
    </View>
}
```